# Homeomorphism betwen Unit circle in the Taxicab Geometry to the Unit circle in the Euclidean Geometry

Tags: general-topology

I need make a homeomorphism to the unit circle in the Taxicab Geometry to the Unit circle in the Euclidean Geometry, but I can't find information about a parametrization to the unit circle in the Taxicab Geometry

Comment: Why would you need a parametrisation? Just draw them both on a piece of paper, and see what you have.

Comment: To write a explicit homeomosphism

Comment: An explicit homeomorphism doesn't have to be typed out using parameterized coordinates and formulas. The answer below is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $x$ on the boundary of the taxicab's unit ball. Draw a line from the origin through $x$. It meets the boundary of the circle at some unique point $f(x)$. Prove that $x\to f(x)$ is a homeomorphism.

Added: Actually $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm, and this same formula provides a homeomorphism between the boundary of the unit ball of any norm and the corresponding boundary of the Euclidean unit ball.